Extend System.Windows.Controls.Button
Is it possible to extend a System.Windows.Controls.Button without creating a custom control?
What I want to do is add a DependencyProperty (ButtonStyle) to a standard button where I can reuse the button, but specify if I want it to be square, rounded corner or curcular (from enum).
Any help appreciated, otherwise I will have to create a custom control for this. Thanks.

What about setting the style of the button accordingly?

Sure I can set the style, but I need some Dependency Property passed from the Window to the Control to dictate the style
